# IMAP email/contacts/calendar

Tags: email, calendar, contacts, imap

I am looking for a program that will handle to the sync of my IMAP @hotmail.com account.
Had a look at Thunderbird and Evolution and I can't seem to see how the sync a the calendar or contacts that I have already setup.

Comment: Thunderbird has an add-on for address called TZpush that is reported to sync addresses with Hotmail.  There are not any solutions for syncing calendar that I have ever found.  IMAP email is easy with Thunderbird.